# transmission/web iptables vpn netns, access netns web app from LAN

Tags: iptables, vpn, transmission

Ubuntu 16.04 headless

Succesfully I have managed to get split routing working under these instructions https://schnouki.net/posts/2014/12/12/openvpn-for-a-single-application-on-linux/
The target is to having only transmission over vpn and everything else through eth0.

I ran the transmission-daemon inside netns and I can connect to transmission web gui through elinks but I can't get it to connect to my LAN network so it's accessible from my desktop computers browser

My configuration is like that

```
ip netns add nordvpn
ip netns exec nordvpn ip addr add 127.0.0.1/8 dev lo
ip netns exec nordvpn ip link set lo up
ip link add vpn0 type veth peer name vpn1
ip link set vpn0 up
ip link set vpn1 netns nordvpn up
ip addr add 10.200.200.1/24 dev vpn0
ip netns exec nordvpn ip addr add 10.200.200.2/24 dev vpn1
ip netns exec nordvpn ip route add default via 10.200.200.1 dev vpn1
iptables -A INPUT \! -i vpn0 -s 10.200.200.0/24 -j DROP
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.200.200.0/24 -o et+ -j MASQUERADE
sysctl -q net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

/lib/systemd/system/transmission-daemon.service

```
[Unit]
Description=Transmission BitTorrent Daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=root
Type=simple
ExecStart=/bin/sh -c 'exec /sbin/ip netns exec nordvpn /usr/bin/sudo -u debian-transmission /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error --config-dir /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info'

ExecReload=/bin/kill -s HUP $MAINPID

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

/etc/transmission/settings.json

```
    {
    "alt-speed-down": 50, 
    "alt-speed-enabled": false, 
    "alt-speed-time-begin": 540, 
    "alt-speed-time-day": 127, 
    "alt-speed-time-enabled": false, 
    "alt-speed-time-end": 1020, 
    "alt-speed-up": 50, 
    "bind-address-ipv4": "0.0.0.0", 
    "bind-address-ipv6": "::", 
    "blocklist-enabled": false, 
    "blocklist-url": "http://www.example.com/blocklist", 
    "cache-size-mb": 4, 
    "dht-enabled": true, 
    "download-dir": "/mnt/NFS/Movies", 
    "download-limit": 100, 
    "download-limit-enabled": 0, 
    "download-queue-enabled": true, 
    "download-queue-size": 5, 
    "encryption": 0, 
    "idle-seeding-limit": 30, 
    "idle-seeding-limit-enabled": false, 
    "incomplete-dir": "/mnt/NFS/Incomplete", 
    "incomplete-dir-enabled": true, 
    "lpd-enabled": false, 
    "max-peers-global": 200, 
    "message-level": 1, 
    "peer-congestion-algorithm": "", 
    "peer-id-ttl-hours": 6, 
    "peer-limit-global": 200, 
    "peer-limit-per-torrent": 50, 
    "peer-port": 51413, 
    "peer-port-random-high": 65535, 
    "peer-port-random-low": 49152, 
    "peer-port-random-on-start": false, 
    "peer-socket-tos": "default", 
    "pex-enabled": true, 
    "port-forwarding-enabled": false, 
    "preallocation": 1, 
    "prefetch-enabled": 1, 
    "queue-stalled-enabled": true, 
    "queue-stalled-minutes": 30, 
    "ratio-limit": 2, 
    "ratio-limit-enabled": false, 
    "rename-partial-files": true, 
    "rpc-authentication-required": false, 
    "rpc-bind-address": "0.0.0.0", 
    "rpc-enabled": true, 
    "rpc-password": "{aaaaabbbbbcccccc", 
    "rpc-port": 9091, 
    "rpc-url": "/transmission/", 
    "rpc-username": "blades", 
    "rpc-whitelist": "127.0.0.1,10.200.200.*,192.168.2.3", 
    "rpc-whitelist-enabled": true, 
    "scrape-paused-torrents-enabled": true, 
    "script-torrent-done-enabled": true, 
    "seed-queue-enabled": false, 
    "seed-queue-size": 10, 
    "speed-limit-down": 100, 
    "speed-limit-down-enabled": false, 
    "speed-limit-up": 100, 
    "speed-limit-up-enabled": false, 
    "start-added-torrents": true, 
    "trash-original-torrent-files": false, 
    "umask": 2, 
    "upload-limit": 100, 
    "upload-limit-enabled": 0, 
    "upload-slots-per-torrent": 14, 
    "utp-enabled": true
}
```

/etc/openvpn/se10.nordvpn.com.udp1194.ovpn

```
    client
dev tun
proto udp
remote 91.236.116.83 1194
resolv-retry infinite
remote-random
nobind
tun-mtu 1500
tun-mtu-extra 32
mssfix 1450
persist-key
persist-tun
ping 15
ping-restart 0
ping-timer-rem
reneg-sec 0

remote-cert-tls server

#mute 10000
auth-user-pass /etc/openvpn/login.conf

comp-lzo
verb 3
pull
fast-io
cipher AES-256-CBC



<ca>
-----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----
bbbb
-----END CERTIFICATE-----
</ca>
key-direction 1
<tls-auth>
#
# 2048 bit OpenVPN static key
#
-----BEGIN OpenVPN Static key V1-----
aaaaa
-----END OpenVPN Static key V1-----
</tls-auth>
```

curl ipv4.icanhazip.com
returns my public ip address

```
systemctl start transmission-daemon
ip netns exec nordvpn openvpn se10.nordvpn.com.udp1194.ovpn
ip netns pids nordvpn
2231
16252
16265
ps aux
root     16252  0.5  0.0   7672  1656 ?        Ss   09:12   0:00 /usr/bin/sudo -u debian-transmission /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error --config-dir /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info
debian-+ 16265  0.5  0.1  30700  3364 ?        Sl   09:12   0:00 /usr/bin/transmission-daemon -f --log-error --config-dir /var/lib/transmission-daemon/info
root      2231  0.0  0.1   6156  2800 ?        S    May12   0:01 openvpn se10.nordvpn.com.udp1194.ovpn
```

And connecting to netns

```
    ip netns exec nordvpn /bin/bash

    curl ipv4.icanhazip.com
```

returns vpn address

What Iam doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I have the almost exact setup and issue.

As far as I can tell, the namespaced network just doesn't want to let itself be access from outside. There is probably some `iptables` rule that can allow `192.168.1.*:9091` to be mapped to `10.200.200.2:9091` but I resorted to using [`socat`](http://www.dest-unreach.org/socat/doc/socat.html#SYNOPSIS) as a workaround to make the `10.200.200.*` network accessible via the actual IP address, `192.168.1.*`

I'm guessing `10.200.200.2` is the ip address that the transmission daemon rpc is bound to in the nordvpn namespace. You should get that info using `ip netns exec nordvpn ifconfig vpn1`. Look for the `inet addr` value.

You can verify that the rpc service is up using `ip netns exec nordvpn transmission-remote --auth <username>:<password> -si` to get the session info.

Then connect virtual network and actual network for port `9091` using socat:

```
socat tcp-listen:9091,reuseaddr,fork tcp-connect:10.200.200.2:9091
```

You can also turn it into a poor man's daemon by running it as a scheduled task using `at`

```
echo 'socat tcp-listen:9091,reuseaddr,fork tcp-connect:10.200.200.2:9091 > /dev/null 2>&1' | at now
```

Note that the `fork` argument for `socat` creates multiple child processes. You can stop these later on using `pkill -f 'socat tcp-listen:9091'`

You should be able to access it from your desktop using your ubuntu box IP after that.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to necro this but it comes up as the relevant search. I have followed the same guide and have the same issues. Ketwaroo's answer didn't work for me so I had to do some extra digging.

Here's what I found:

### **socat solution:**

```
sudo socat tcp-listen:9091,fork,reuseaddr exec:'ip netns exec vpn socat STDIO "tcp-connect:10.200.200.2:9091"',nofork
```

Thanks to the author from this site: https://newbedev.com/port-forwarding-to-application-in-network-namespace-with-vpn for the working solution AND *a systemd service file* if you want to keep the socat solution

### **iptables solution:**

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 9091 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.200.200.2:9091
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -p tcp --dport 9091 -j MASQUERADE
```

thanks to the author here: https://npre.wordpress.com/2012/09/15/port-forwarding-with-iptables/ for the insight for this.

I kept thinking there had to be an iptables entry through the network namespace but I was wrong, these 2 entries do what's required.

Hope this helps others who are trying to have some kind of port routing from LAN to a network namespace.